# Django dumpdata from multiple databases

Tags: python, django

Running on Django 3.2 I use `dumpdata -o db.json -a` to export multiple databases to .json.
Looking into dumpdata.py, it retrieves all objects from a model by calling

```
queryset = objects.using(using).order_by(model._meta.pk.name)
```

https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py, line 185

My problem is that in my case, using is set to 'default' by default, even though I use --all parameter.  And later, when calling `objects.using(using)` it tries to retrieve all objects from default database, even though it's supposed to be 'MIFIR'. What did I do wrong? Have I misconfigured something in my database? I set the app_label in _meta and added my app_label to dbrouter.py, I can see it resolving database name correctly.

[Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/547sg.png), [Still tries to use default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KShrl.png), [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbSEv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can use `--database` to specify a databse.
Also keep in mind that to add new database to Django project you need to create a DBRouter for that database. Not sure, but that might be the problem...